# UITableViewCell prototype cell across various UITableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboard

A UITableViewCell prototype cell seems to be can only be created under a UITableView. How can I use the same prototype cell in different UITableViews using storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it.
I usually end up refactoring the Cell into a separate XIB (you can copy / paste out of the Storyboard) then calling:

`- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

on the `UITableView` in `viewDidLoad`